# Sequence of sets with limit contains finitely many elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Can we have a decreasing sequence of sets with all members containing countably infinitely many elements whose limit only has finitely many elements? If so, what are some examples?

(Not very sure what tags to use)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one: Let $X_n = \Bbb N \setminus \{i\mid 0 < i < n\}$, so that $X_0 = \Bbb N$ (which contains $0$), and $X_{n+1} \subsetneq X_n$. Then 
$$
\lim_{n\ge 0} X_n = \bigcap_{n\ge 0} X_n = \{0\}.
$$
It's easy to generalize the definition of the $X_n$ so that their intersection is any given finite set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know of any examples that don't fit inside this generalisation you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Take $A_n=\{ 1,n+1,n+2, \cdots\}$.

Then $$\cap A_n= \{1\}.$$